# Как сделать подписанный хэшем JSON?

Tags: php, json, api, платежи

Помогите пожалуйста. Я не могу понять как создать транзакцию и отправить POST запрос И вообще как работать с этим API. Я прочитал документацию но ничего не понял. Пожалуйста помогите - проект стоит

Вот API - https://docs.cityhub.com.ua/introduction.html

Думаю на земле еще есть хорошие люди.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

В целом, в документации всё написано, хотя и немного непоследовательно.

1. Формируем массив в указанном формате, с пустой строкой на месте хэша
2. Сортируем так чтобы ключи шли в алфавитом порядке
3. Делаем JSON encode
4. Формируем хэш MD5 из строки вида джейсон + токен
5. Подставлям хэш в массив
6. Делаем JSON encode и полученный джейсон отправляем

Дальше это все надо *просто написать на РНР*

```
$token = 111;

$data = [
    'auth' => [
        'point' => '33_44', 
        'hash' => '',
    ],
    'locale' => 'ru', 
    'service_id' => 999,
    'amount' => 1000,
    'fields' => [
        'account' => '1112233',
    ],
];
ksort($data);
$json = json_encode($data);
$hash = md5($json . $token);
$data['auth']['hash'] = $hash;
$json = json_encode($data);
```

и дальше отправлем полученный джейсон.

Токен должны выдать при регистрации